# Subgroups in $G$ of the form $gHg^{-1}$

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of finite index. Prove that there is only a finite number of distinct subgroups in $G$ of the form $gHg^{-1}$ where $g$ belongs to $G$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $g'\in gH$, what can you say about $g'H(g')^{-1}$?